# How to check if data are the same between to Mysql servers setup as master-master replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have two servers using Mysql Master-Master replication. Actually, only one server receives write orders.
One of the databases is out of sync.  Several tables don't have the same numbers of records, or the same value for autoinc (which is configured with a step of two to work on master-master).

How to check the others databases? Is there a tool to do it? A tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use Percona tools for such check [Percona toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/)

I think that this 2 tools should help

[pt-table-cheksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-table-checksum.html)
[pt-heartbeat](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-heartbeat.html)